Understand snakemake threads
I wonder why there are two thread numbers in the Snakemake printcmd output:
rule bwa:
    input: ...
    output: 
    threads: 8
    resources: mem_mb=20480, mem_mib=19532, disk_mb=1024, disk_mib=977, tmpdir=<TBD>, threads=2, runtime=60

One is "threads: 8" and the other one "threads=2". I checked the 8 one seems correct. But why "threads=2" exists?
Thanks.

It should be noted that the specified threads have to be seen as a maximum. When Snakemake is executed with fewer cores, the number of threads will be adjusted.
